# RSS feed validity and Google Adsense

Tags: feed, feedburner, adsense

I want to use Google Adsense code snippets in my blog posts, so in my single.php.
However, when I do so, then my RSS feed becomes invalid because of the javascript code in the content and the feed won't be updated anymore.

Is there ANY way to fix this?

I still have the Google Adsense code in the sidebar where it's not causing any issues.

I've seen lots of blogs that have Google ads in their blog posts and a functioning RSS feed, so it seems to be possible, but how?
Or rather, why is it causing problems in my case?

I've done a looooooooot of research, but couldn't find ANY information about this issue.
I think that means that it's not a very common problem.
I really hope somebody can help me with this BIG problem.

Would something like this work? http://chaosinacan.com/programming/adsense-without-blocking/

For reference, here's my website: http://zoomingjapan.com/

Here's my feed: http://zoomingjapan.com/feed/

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How do you add the adsense code to the blog posts?

Comment: @toscho Well, because I didn't want to lose the validity of my feed, I took all the codes out again, but I did put every single code in directly into each post as I was still experimenting a lot.
Later on I wanted to place a code snippet into the single.php instead, but that would be essentially the same thing, right?

Comment: @toscho I assume your question means that there are different ways to implement the code to your blog posts. Could you enlighten me, please?

Comment: Well, I _guess,_ it is a filter for `the_content`, but I really have to see that to give answer.

Comment: @toscho Sure! Let me know what exactly you need to see and I'll provide the code :)

Comment: Do you use a plugin, or do you copy the adsense code manually into the post? If you are using a plugin – which one?

Comment: @toscho I'm not using a plugin. I copy and paste the code as is from the Google Adsense page into each of my blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not paste the Adsense code into the blog posts. Use a plugin instead.

Sample Plugin:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Zoomingjapan Adsense */

add_filter( 'the_content', 'zoomingjapan_adsense' );

function zoomingjapan_adsense( $content )
{
    if ( is_feed() or ! is_singular() )
        return $content;

    $adsense = '<adense code, replace that!>';

    // remove all existing script elements
    $content = preg_replace("~<script[^>]*>.+</script[^>]*>~i", '', $content );

    return $content . $adsense;
}
```

Usage:

- Change the content of the variable `$adsense` to whatever you need.
- Put the file into `wp-content/plugins/`.
- Activate it in `wp-admin/plugins.php`.

That’s all.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.
I suppose I put that code into my function.php
Where whould I put the Adsense code? Where it says "adsense cde, replace that!"?

I wanted to implement something in my single.php anyways where I can easily change the code and position of the ads all at once. Something like this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-insert-ads-within-your-post-content-in-wordpress/

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web/72183#72183) for the _where_ (plugin, not theme!). And, **please,** ignore that terrible tutorial. They are doing it wrong. It hurts just to look at that, ah, it huuuurtssss …

Comment: *LOL* Ok, I'll forget about that tutorial. I understand now how to create a new plugin for the code you provided in the answer. 
I still don't understand where to insert the actual Adsense code. Yeah, I'm THAT stupid, I guess :/ ...

Comment: Replace the strin `'<adense code, replace that!>'` with the adsense code.

Comment: Thanks again. That means I'll be able to place only one type of code and not various kinds of Adsense codes with this plugin, right?

Comment: You could [use a conditional tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71527/exclude-custom-function-content-from-certain-pages/71529#71529) and send context specific code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really busy at the moment and will try what you suggested some other time. If it works, I'll mark your answer as accepted. If not, I'll let you know what the problem was. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm finally back and have time to try this now. I created a adsense.php file with the code you provided. That will be my plugin. I don't understand how I can install such a plugin. Is it enough to just upload the .php file to all the other theme files? Will it work if I use the automatic plugin uploader that Wordpress provides? Also, once the plugin is installed, how can I call the function of the plugin in my single.php? Thanks so much!

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: Thank you. I did as you said. I already got a warning that some of the characters in the plugin might cause errors when activating the plugin. Then, I tried to call the function using the following '<?php if(function_exists('zoomingjapan_adsense')) zoomingjapan_adsense(); ?>' 
Then I got an error message like this: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-content/plugins/adsense.php:1) in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881
How can I fix this?
I changed the code you provided and added ...

Comment: '; ?>' at the end of the plugin. Now, I don't get an error message anymore, but when I call the function (like explained in my previous comment) NOTHING happens. No Adsense code is being inserted in my blog post.

Comment: The exact error message I get when I try to activate the plugin that you suggested is: The plugin generated 3 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Comment: [Remove the BOM](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74154/73)

Comment: Ok, vielen Dank!
I don't get the mentioned error message anymore, but when I use '<?php if(function_exists('zoomingjapan_adsense')) zoomingjapan_adsense(); ?>' to call the function, nothing happens. Am I calling it wrong?

Comment: This function is a *filter* you have to pass some content to it. The plugin does that automatically.

Comment: It shows up, I just didn't see it as it showed up at the end of the blog post. How can I now change its position?
Would you recommend trying one of the many Adsense plugins out there? They seem to give you a lot of control aobut where to put ads.

Comment: Could you maybe insert in your original answer how I can: 1) Add more than 1 ad code. 2) Put it to any position I'd live (e.g. before the last paragraph within my blog post). 3) Make it align-center.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to use a plugin called "Ad Inserter" which does pretty much what I want, but I think it's not coded well. I get the following error message when using the plugin: Zeitstempel: 10.12.2012 14:07:15
Fehler: Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString' (everything works, but it shows me that there's this Javascript error).

Comment: Sorry, this thread crossed the _too localized_ line long ago, and I really don’t have the time for further support or a probably long chat session.

Comment: That's okay. I'll mark your answer as accepted for now as it did help. It's not your fault that I'm too much of a beginner to know how to solve things by myself. Thanks.