# Conditional for a Single Post That Belongs to a Category?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I have categories like `gaming` and `movies` on my website and when a user visits any of these categories the content in the sidebar is displayed depending on the category they are in.  So gaming content for the gaming category, movie related content for movies.

When a user selects a post in either of these categories, I have it defaulting to the sidebar that displays on the home page since I don't know how to keep the sidebar displaying the same content that is on the category pages.

The closest I could get would be something like `<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>`.  How would I add `is_category( 'gaming' )` so it can target a `single page` (single.php) that belongs to the category `gaming?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine conditions:

```
if ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['post'] )
   && is_single()
   && in_category( 'gaming', $GLOBALS['post'] ) 
)
{
   // do something
}
```

See [PHP manual: Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and [Exclude custom function content from certain pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71527/exclude-custom-function-content-from-certain-pages/71529#71529).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `in_category`?

Comment: Uhm, yes. :) And a `post` object should be passed too. Fixed.