# How to get type of archive whether it is post or date or category archive?

Tags: archives, conditional-tags, conditional-content, custom-post-type-archives

using function `is_archive()` we can know whether it is archive page or not.

But if it is archive page how can i find whether it is author archive page or category archive or date archive.

I have found this code in wp-includes/query.php

```
if ( $this->is_post_type_archive || $this->is_date || $this->is_author || $this->is_category || $this->is_tag || $this->is_tax )
$this->is_archive = true;
```

but dont know how to use it in wp_head action.

Based on archive page category or author or date archive, i want to out put specific meta tags in header.

Any help???

Thanks in advanced.

wordpress.stackexchange.com rocks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just the functions, not the object properties:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive() or is_date() )
```

There are [many conditional functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71529/73) (returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`) for exactly these cases.

Comment: brilliant.. i missed them completly.. Thanks exactly what i want. Will accept your answer soon.