# do_action in header, add action later?

Tags: actions

I want to include the facebook JSSDK only on pages where I want to use it. On the facebook dev site it sais that ideally its included right after the opening body tag, which sits in header.php

My thought was to add in header.php

```
<?php do_action( 'topofthetop'); ?>
```

right after the opening body tag.

And then later (in comments.php just before `<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>`), if I need to call

```
add_action( 'topofthetop', array('someclass','FB_JS_SDK') );
```

FB_JS_SDK simply echoes the code needed to included the FB-JSSDK.
But the code doesn't appear after the body tag. I guess because header.php is allready output before my add_action call?

How could I solve this?

Comment: When exactly do you call `add_action()`?

Comment: in comments.php just before "if ( have_comments() ) :"  (I'm using a twenty twelve child theme)

Comment: This cannot work. Try registering the callback before you use `add_action()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must register callbacks before they are called (`add_action()` and `add_filter()` are registration functions, they remember what to do when).

Try the following in your `functions.php` or in your plugin:

```
add_action( 'topofthetop', 'load_FB_JS_SDK' );

function load_FB_JS_SDK()
{
    if ( is_singular() && have_comments() )
        someclass::FB_JS_SDK();
}
```

Comment: but how do I then manage to run someclass::FB_JS_SDK() only on the pages I want to use it?

Comment: Inspect the current page in the callback function. There are many other [conditional functions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71529/73) available and the global `$post` object too.

Comment: one more question on this, as far as I understand it, the callback is run, when do_action is called, therefore right after the body tag. Doesn't that mean I'm not yet in the loop? How does have_comments() work then?

Comment: `have_comments()` looks at the global `$wp_query` object. This is already set up, otherwise WordPress couldn’t even load the template.

Comment: so it refers to comments for the page, not to comments made on a post?

Comment: The post type doesn’t matter, can be `post`, `page` or anything else.

Comment: I have to do more reading on this, thanks a lot for your patience, this gives some good starting points!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hook it in from your child themes functions file using a conditional tag.

```
function facebook_comments_sdk_script() {


wp_enqueue_script( 'facebook-sdk', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . 

'/js/fb-comments.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'facebook_comments_sdk_script' );


function load_facebook_comments_form() {

if ( comments_open() ) {

echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/comments"   

data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';

   }

}

add_action('comment_form', 'load_facebook_comments_form');
```

I also removed the scripts tags from the Javascript SDK and put it in a file like this:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789224439";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```