# error:-Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: wp-config

whewn ever i try to login http://affiliatesurge.com.au/wp-admin/

i got ""
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/affiliat/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/affiliat/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881 ""

Error ... i already try removing spacing in wp-config and functions.php

Comment: Disable  your plugins one by one then switch to the default theme. Does that help you narrow it down?

Answer (score 3):

You saved your `wp-config.php` with a [Byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). Save the file again without the BOM.

In Linux or Mac OS X open the file with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), enter …

```
:set nobomb
```

… and save it.

In Windows open it in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and convert it to **UTF-8 without BOM**:

[image]

Comment: That is often the reason for having a few pixels of white space on top of the screen. Always check if your files are saved as UTF-8 without BOM. Be careful though - as long as you do not use any special characters like the German ö, your Editor can not tell if the file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM or as ANSI, as they are identical. The real trouble starts as soon as you use special characters, but your editor saves them as ANSI, even though you have all your other files as UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your WordPress' `wp-config.php` on the first line:

```
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: You should explain *why*...

Comment: Explaining why helps us understand the context and rationale.